# Compare multiple cells from one row (EXCEL)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I really don't know if I am at the right place to ask this question, but I didn't find an answer anywhere. I am looking for an Excel formula (no macro or dynamic stuff) to compare the text values of 6 cells in the same row.

Suppose that I have the row C2:H2 which contains : A B B C A A

I would like to have a way to compare all those 6 values together by those criterias :

A = wildcard (e.g. N/A), no impact.

B = Source 1

C = Source 2

My goal is to flag that line that contains more than one source (B and C).

Is there a way to do so?

PRECISION :
I want to compare the cells between them.

Each line is distinct.

However, the 6 columns are "Sources" and I want to create a cell on column 7 that could flag if the line contain more than one source (A doesn't count, it has to be excluded).

Comment: Compare the cells with what? It might be a good idea for you to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1466721/edit) to provide sample data, desired outcome what you have tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations

Comment: I want to compare the cells between them. Each line is distinct. However, the 6 columns are "Sources" and I want to create a cell on column 7 that could flag if the line contain more than one source (A doesn't count, it has to be excluded).

Comment: To rephrase the question: You want a formula to indicate whether the range `C2:H2` contains at least one `B` and at least one `C`. Is that right? I.E., the values `AABBAA` would return false because `A` is ignored and only `B` is used while `AABCAA` would return true because it has both `B` and `C`.

Comment: This is almost "right". The fact is that many "source" can be added furthermore. It can be A, B, C, D, Z, E, etc.

I would like to know if there's a way to "flag" if more than one source (except A) is used....

I am sure there's a way, but I am not able to find it to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @Engineer Toast's rephrasing of your question is correct, this should work:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(C2:H2,"B")>=1,COUNTIF(C2:H2,"C")>=1),"multiple sources","")
```

Comment: This is almost "right". The fact is that many "source" can be added furthermore. It can be A, B, C, D, Z, E, etc.

I would like to know if there's a way to "flag" if more than one source (except A) is used....

I am sure there's a way, but I am not able to find it to be honest...